# CSS differing link styling

Tags: css, focus, hover, hyperlink

From what I know using something like:

```
.class a {}
```

Is the same as using:

```
.class a:link {}
```

Right?

Additionally..... are the following two styles the same?

```
.class a:focus {}
.class a:hover {}
```

Lastly..... the following styling is the color it is when the mouse is down right?

```
.class a:active {}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- `a` is every anchor element.
- `a:link` is only when the hyperlink has never been visited.
- `a:focus` is when you're tabbing through the page with a keyboard.
- `a:hover` is when your mouse is over the link.
- `a:active` is when you mousedown the link.
- `a:visited` is when you've already visited that link.

Comment: `a` and `a:link` are **not** the same thing. `a` matches any `<a>` elements while `a:link` only matches `<a>` elements that are unvisited hyperlinks.

Comment: @BoltClock Thanks for the clarification. I've updated my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 2):

- :link = Only links you haven't
  already visited
- :visited = Links you have already visited
- :focus = For elements in focus, like when you use the tabulator
- :hover = When you move your mouse over it
- :active = for just clicked links