# Link styling behaviour in IE6

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6, css-selectors

I came across this issue when testing a stylesheet across different browsers, including IE6 (yes, I know..)

```
<head>
<style>
  a:link, a:visited, a:hover, a:active { font-weight: bold; color: #000; text-decoration: underline }
  .myclass a { color: red; text-decoration: none; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p>This is a <a href="1">test</a></p>
<div class="myclass">
<p>This is a <a href="2">test</a></p>
</div>
</body>
```

Results:

- In IE6, the `.myclass a` rule only applies to the unvisited link state
- In other browsers (FF, Chrome), the `.myclass a` rule applies to all link states

I believe that IE6 is wrong and that `.myclass a`, with no pseudo-classes specified, should apply to all link states. However I came across [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629923/css-differing-link-styling) where it says that `a` is equivalent to `a:link`. This would match the behaviour in IE6. However I cannot find any official reference confirming this.

Which one is right?

**Update:**

As noted in the comments, the accepted answer to the question referenced above has since been updated.

Comment: The first thing I thought is that IE6 was getting it wrong. However I got confused by that statement in both the question and the accepted answer, and also by the fact that after some googling I could not find any reference or mention of such a bug anywhere (whereas most IE6 bugs tend to be quite well known by now and it is often easy to find information about them...)

Comment: The accepted answer to that question has since been updated.

Comment: Updated the text of the question as well to clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other browsers are right; IE6 is wrong.

The selector `a` should match any `<a>` elements, while `a:link` only matches `<a>` elements that are *unvisited hyperlinks* (the HTML 4 document type defines hyperlinks as `<a>` elements with a `href` attribute). Nowhere does it state in either specification that `a` should automatically translate to `a:link` or vice versa.

Since there's no such translation going on, your two CSS rules have equally specific selectors (your class selector shares equal specificity with *each* of your pseudo-classes). So, your second rule is supposed to override the first rule for any `<a>` elements within `div.myclass`, regardless of their link state, thereby making it always red and with no text decoration.

By the way, IE7 also fails to apply the `font-weight: bold` style when you test with an `<a>` element in `div.myclass` that isn't a link, even though it's supposed to as there is no overriding `font-weight` style in your second rule:

```
<div class="myclass">
<p>This is a <a href="2">test</a></p>
<p>This is a <a>test</a></p> <!-- does not bold on hover in IE7! -->
</div>
```

Comment: This is how I would interpret it based on what is stated here: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#link-pseudo-classes

Answer (score -1):

IE6 is right. Not specifying a pseudo-class on `a` is the same as `:link`. Therefore you must specify styles for `:link` and `:visited` if you want something specific - `:hover` and `:active` are optional.

Comment: Sorry, this is wrong. `a:link` is not supposed to pick up `<a>` elements that aren't unvisited hyperlinks (that don't have a `href`).

Comment: @Kolink: Thanks for the answer. However, can you point out where is this behaviour actually defined? I did not find it in the CSS specs. The way I read it, in the absence of pseudo-classes, a type selector would match all elements of that type...